# Select all text from input boxes

Tags: html, css, select, text, input

How can I select all text (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) or drag select multiple text input boxes?

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/vkgaw6xz/)

```css
* {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    -moz-user-select:text;
    -webkit-user-select:text;
    -khtml-user-select:text;
    -ms-user-select:text;
    user-select:text;
}
```

```html
<input type=text value="catch me">
<input type=text value="if you can!!!">
```

Comment: I just did `
catch me
 
if you can!!!
` .. by starting outside the input field (with mouse) and move down-left

Comment: And again `
catch me
 
if you can!!!
` ... by pushing Ctrl+A and then right click-copy

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking, please clarify what you intend to accomplish.